# XML request from apex

Tags: httprequest, xml

I need to post some data to server using XML.

The XML body of my request is

```
        requestBody = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xmlreq><record name="direct" status="new"><field name="company-name">Test2</field></record></xmlreq>';
```

I use this request

```
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        req.setEndpoint(URL);
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setBody(body);
        req.setTimeout(120000);
        req.setCompressed(true);
        Http http = new Http();
        try {
            res = http.send(req);
            System.debug('Callout OK: ' + res.getBody());
        } catch (System.CalloutException e) {
            System.debug('Callout error: ' + e);
            System.debug(res.toString());
        }
```

In response, I get a phrase - Unable to read the input data.
Error on my part or on the server-side? I think that there is an error in my XML or in a way of its transfers to the server.

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure the target system accepts a compressed body?

Answer (score 0):

That XML is fine, though I would generally recommend you use [Dom.Document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_xml_dom_document.htm) to generate your XML. However, you did not specify a Content-Type, which may cause your application to not understand the data you're passing in. Try:

```
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this didn't solve my issue (i got the same issue). Maybe we need some other approach?